# How to change the date format from "03-Nov-2016" to 11/3/2016

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the **python** code I tried in 2.7 ,

```
def date_format_change():
    DB_date = "03-NOV-2016"
    split2 = DB_date.split('-')
    print split2[0]
    M_date = float(round(split2[0]),2)
    print M_date
    Month = {'JAN': '1', 'FEB': '2', 'MAR': '3', 'APR': '4', 'MAY': '5','JUN': '6', 'JUL': '7', 'AUG': '8', 'SEP': '9',
    'OCT': '10', 'NOV': '11', 'DEC': '12'}
    DB_Month = str(split2[1])
    print DB_Month
    M_Month = int(Month[DB_Month])
    M_year = split2(2)
    print M_year
    Changed_format = str(M_Month) +"/"+ str(M_date)+"/"+ str(M_year)
    print Changed_format

date_format_change()
```

but I am getting error saying :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aannam002c/workspace/Website/Century/views.py", line 17, in <module>
03
    date_format_change()
  File "C:/Users/aannam002c/workspace/Website/Century/views.py", line 5, in date_format_change
    M_date = float(round(split2[0]),2)
TypeError: a float is required

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could any one can help with this?

Comment: `split2` keeps strings so you can't round text "03" - you need `int("03")` to convert text into number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**float()** takes one argument and you have given **two** and also float type for dates doesn't look good. **int** would do the job. Also, `round` takes a number while `split2[0]` is a string.

This is probably what you want:

```
def date_format_change():
    DB_date = "03-NOV-2016"
    split2 = DB_date.split('-')
    M_date = int(split2[0])
    Month = {'JAN': '1', 'FEB': '2', 'MAR': '3', 'APR': '4', 'MAY': '5','JUN': '6', 'JUL': '7', 'AUG': '8', 'SEP': '9',
    'OCT': '10', 'NOV': '11', 'DEC': '12'}
    print (M_date)
    DB_Month = split2[1]
    print (DB_Month)
    M_Month = int(Month[DB_Month])
    M_year = split2[2]
    print (M_year)
    Changed_format = str(M_Month) +"/"+ str(M_date)+"/"+ str(M_year)
    print (Changed_format)

date_format_change()
```

It returns:

```
3
NOV
2016
11/3/2016
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution for your problem:

```
from datetime import datetime
DB_date = "03-NOV-2016"
print datetime.strptime(DB_date, '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The result of this is `11/03/2016`, not `11/3/2016` as requested.

Comment: Yes my month needs to be in "3" and not "03" format. Anyway thanks much for your view.

Answer (score 0):

I am particularly fond of the [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. It makes the first step in parsing dates an absolute breeze. Just throw at it a string that somewhat resembles a date, or reference to time and it will convert it to a `datetime` for you.

```
$ pip install dateparser
```

Once it is installed:

```
import dateparser
from datetime import datetime

DB_date = "03-NOV-2016"
date = dateparser.parse(DB_date)

print datetime.datetime.strftime(date, '%m/%-d/%Y')

# Output: 11/3/2016
```